# jQuery Cross-site Call To ASMX service Return value null

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asmx, cross-site

I am trying to call a asmx service from an HTML page through JavaScript and jQuery. 
Here is my code for the service HelloWorldTest.asmx:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HelloWorldTest : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string HelloWorld5()
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pollConString"].ToString();
        Random _rg = new Random();
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        sql = "insert into Country (OID,country_name) values( 'Servicecalled-" + Convert.ToString(_rg.Next(0, 99999999)).PadLeft(8, '0') + "','"+System.DateTime.Now.ToString() +"')";

        connection.Open();
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        return "Helloworld";
    }
}
```

I have published the service in a local server, which is running in 192.168.0.124 and port 80.

Now here is my HTML page code for the client call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: http://192.168.0.124:80/pollservice/Services/HelloWorldTest.asmx/HelloWorld5',
    processData: true,
    data: {},               
    dataType: "json; charset=utf-8",
    responseType: "",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        processData(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
});

function processData(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                  
    alert(' data d = ' + data.d); 
}
```

Now the issue:

when I am running into the localhost I get a return from the service. It is a simple string. But, when I am publishing it into the server in a LAN and I am invoking from client machine, then I am getting null output.

**But, Interestingly, the log is written into the server. So the Helloworld5() method is called from the JavaScript method through $.ajax(....) call . But the JSON return data is empty in the case of the published server.**

Why this is happening? I am running the published website in Asp.Net integrated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of the [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) if the html and the asmx service are running in different servers.
To enable cross origin ajax requests, you have to use [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) or CORS.

To ensure that this is a cross origin issue you can use the chrome developer tools, where you will get a message "Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in case of cross origin issues.

I had a similar issue and i ended up using JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

you're declaring the return type as JSON, but actually returning a naked string. you probably want to build the JSON data before returning it, e.g.:

```
// ...

string responseData = "{ d : \"";
responseData += "Hello World!";
responseData += "\" }";

return responseData;
```

Comment: Thanks Eliran. I have format JSON string as of your comments. But still No Progress. Looking forward to this issue...